# Order by Consecutive Numbers in SQL Server Select

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I was wondering if there is a way to order by consecutive numbers in SQL Server 2008.

Currently I have

```
Select DISTINCT StoreNum, StoreName, Date, Time
From tbl_stores
ORDER BY StoreNum, Date
```

Which will give me

```
1 | Toronto Store  | 2015-03-04 | 12:44:44 |
1 | Toronto Store  | 2015-03-04 | 12:44:45 |
2 | Chatham Store  | 2015-03-05 | 12:44:47 | 
2 | Chatham Store  | 2015-03-05 | 12:44:48 | 
3 | London Store   | 2015-03-06 | 12:44:51 |
3 | London Store   | 2015-03-06 | 12:44:52 |
```

Is it possible to order by `StoreNum` consecutively then date? Like this

```
1 | Toronto Store   | 2015-03-04 | 12:44:44 |
2 | Chatham Store   | 2015-03-05 | 12:44:47 | 
3 | London Store    | 2015-03-06 | 12:44:51 |
1 | Toronto Store   | 2015-03-04 | 12:44:45 |
2 | Chatham Store   | 2015-03-05 | 12:44:48 | 
3 | London Store    | 2015-03-06 | 12:44:52 |
```

Latest Attempt:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT StoreNum, StoreName, Date, Time,(
    Select StoreNum, StoreName, Date, Time,
           row_number() over (partition by StoreNum order by Date, Time) as seqnum
    From tbl_stores AS q
    order by seqnum, StoreNum, Date,Time
    )
    FROM q
```

Comment: It seems like the results that you want are exactly what you would get if you do `....ORDER BY Date, StoreNum`

Comment: @Lamak No, the results are identicle. Am I missing something?

Comment: @mti2935 No, the results are identicle. Am I missing something?

Comment: Well, the results on your questions were edited, so now the comments are invalid

Comment: @Lamak, I added time instead of ... as I thought maybe they were causing confusion. Sorry

Comment: Not only that, you also changed the date of the desired results, so the comments posted no longer work for that requirement

Comment: Isn't this what Group By is for? `Select Field1, Field2, Field3 from myTable where myFilterTerms Group By Field1, Field2, Field3` ?

Comment: No, GROUP BY can never be relied on to order anything. Only ORDER BY can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the idea (but without the `distinct`).  Use `row_number()` to enumerate by the values within each store, then order by that:

```
Select StoreNum, StoreName, Date, Time,
       row_number() over (partition by StoreNum order by Date, Time) as seqnum
From tbl_stores
order by seqnum, StoreNum, Date;
```

EDIT:

Something like:

```
Select StoreNum, StoreName, Date, Time,
       row_number() over (partition by StoreNum order by Date, Time) as seqnum
From (select distinct StoreNum, StoreName, Date, Time
      from tbl_stores s
     ) s
order by seqnum, StoreNum, Date;
```

Comment: Thank you very much as this is very close to what I need. Is it impossible to use distinct with this?

Comment: @clamchoda . . . It should be possible, but I would put the distinct in a subquery and then do the `row_number()` in the outer query.

Comment: Please see my latest attempt, I keep getting invalid object name 'q'. I have not used row_number() over partition ect, Please help me where I am going wrong

Comment: I went with your first one and redisgned my DB because Distinct was hurting my execution time